# Route traffic for a single IP out of eth0, the rest out of wlan0

Tags: networking, routing

I have my laptop connected to an internal network on `eth0` and an external network on `wlan0`.

How can I configure my routes to forwarded all traffic for `10.1.1.1` out of `eth0`, and *everything* else out of `wlan0`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
ip route add 10.1.1.1/32 dev eth0
```

So when you ping 10.1.1.1 it will route via eth0.

Comment: Yes, this will work if wlan0 is the default gateway of the laptop